# How to read and write a font file?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

Lately I have been getting into font creation, and for the most part, I have been using software and website (such as fontstruct).

While these websites give me some control over the fonts, they do not give me much. I was wondering if there was a way to learn how to write a font from scratch.

Is this possible, and if so how?

I also know that in terms of time, this might not be the best way to go about it, but I am curious, and if possible, I would like to try it out.

Comment: Have you tried [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/)? It's complicated, clunky and overwhelming, but it's *free* and it works.

Comment: I have *not* tried FontForge; the reason being "it's complicated, clunky and overwhelming" (I have heard similar things). I am open to trying, however

Comment: Since I've only designed fonts for fun, I haven't tried working with a professional font program like [FontLab](https://www.fontlab.com/) as it costs $459 which is too much for this hobby for me. But I suspect that the *complexity* is the same just presented better and with more nifty tools to speed up the process. It really just *is* complicated to create a font with all the characters, accents, kerning etc. etc.

Comment: @Wolff i disagree a little. You can do a font with just a text editor. But still fonts are hard to design well because they are very emergent, and doing kerning is ridiculously much work.

Comment: @joojaa, I understand what you mean, but don't you just move the complexity from the screen to your brain?

Comment: @Wolff but my point is that its not a unapproachable task at all. Even kids do it in school. Its just that because its highly emergent it means you are likely to come up with nonoptimal solutions quite a lot. But its a lot of work to do a comprehensive typeface. But thats all, a lot of work.